# "Error provisioning azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks with Terraform on Azure"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I'm encountering a challenging issue while trying to provision an azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks resource using Terraform on Azure. Despite my best efforts, I'm consistently facing an error that I can't seem to resolve.

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks" "example" {
  name                = "exampleLinkedService"
  data_factory_id     = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  databricks_workspace = azurerm_databricks_workspace.example.name
  linked_service_name = "exampleDatabricksLinkedService"
}
```

```
Error: Error creating/updating Azure Databricks Linked Service: linkedServices - Error when processing request: Data factory operation failed: Linked service operation failed: {"error":{"code":"LinkedServiceCreationFailed","message":"Linked service 'exampleDatabricksLinkedService' creation failed: 'Linked service 'exampleDatabricksLinkedService' creation failed. More details: [\n{\n\"code\": \"LinkedServiceDatabricksValidationError\",\n\"message\": \"The specified Azure Databricks linked service 'exampleDatabricksLinkedService' linked service properties are not valid. Please ensure that the linked service properties are correct.\"\n}\n]'"}}.
```

Any inputs can be apprieciated.

To configure the requirement azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks

Comment: Please mention the code causing the error. @Nature

Comment: Are you using a managed identity & new cluster for this case or the existing one? @nature

Comment: I attempted to use a newly created cluster in this context, and I require an understanding of the underlying reason that led to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to compensate the error mentioned casued while provisioning azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks with Terraform on Azure and I was able to provision requirement successfully.

The error caused due to the `databricks_workspace` attribute in your `azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks` resource should specify the name of your Azure Databricks workspace, not the workspace's `name`. If you're using the workspace's `name` attribute, change it to use the `resource_group_name` attribute.

Ensure that the `linked_service_name` attribute is a valid name for your linked service. It should adhere to naming conventions and not contain any special characters or spaces.

**My terrafrom configuration**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "DataFactory9278vksb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

#Create a databricks instance
resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "databricks-testvk"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks" "msi_linked" {
  name            = "ADBLinkedServiceViaMSIvk"
  data_factory_id = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  description     = "ADB Linked Service via MSI"
  adb_domain      = "https://${azurerm_databricks_workspace.example.workspace_url}"

  msi_work_space_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.example.id

  new_cluster_config {
    node_type             = "Standard_NC12"
    cluster_version       = "5.5.x-gpu-scala2.11"
    min_number_of_workers = 1
    max_number_of_workers = 5
    driver_node_type      = "Standard_NC12"
    log_destination       = "dbfs:/logs"

    custom_tags = {
      custom_tag1 = "sct_value_1"
      custom_tag2 = "sct_value_2"
    }

    spark_config = {
      config1 = "value1"
      config2 = "value2"
    }

    spark_environment_variables = {
      envVar1 = "value1"
      envVar2 = "value2"
    }

    init_scripts = ["init.sh", "init2.sh"]
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

ref: [azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks)